# Use return value of one method as a parameter for another method within the same class

Tags: python, methods, parameters

I am trying to make a class consisting of several methods and I want to use return values from methods as parameters for other methods within the same class. Is it possible to do so?

```
class Result_analysis():
    def __init__(self, confidence_interval):
        self.confidence_interval = confidence_interval

    def read_file(self, file_number):
        dict_ = {1: 'Ten_Runs_avg-throughput_scalar.csv',
                 2: 'Thirty_Runs_avg-throughput_scalar.csv',
                 3: 'Hundred_Runs_avg-throughput_scalar.csv',
                 4: 'Thousand_Runs_avg-throughput_scalar.csv'}
        cols = ['run', 'ber', 'timelimit', 'repetition', 'Module', 'Avg_Throughput']
        data = pd.read_csv(dict_[file_number], delimiter=',', skiprows=[0], names=cols)

        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        return df

    def extract_arrays(self,df):
    df = Result_analysis().read_file(file_number)
        avgTP_10s_arr = []
        avgTP_100s_arr = []
        avgTP_1000s_arr = []

        for i in range(len(data)):
            if (df['timelimit'][i] == 10):
                avgTP_10s_arr.append(df['Avg_Throughput'][i])
            elif (df['timelimit'][i] == 100):
                avgTP_100s_arr.append(df['Avg_Throughput'][i])
            elif (df['timelimit'][i] == 1000):
                avgTP_1000s_arr.append(df['Avg_Throughput'][i])
        return avgTP_10s_arr, avgTP_100s_arr, avgTP_1000s_arr

d =  Result_analysis(0.95)
d.read_file(1)
d.exextract_arrays(d.read_file(1))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-485309654e5c> in <module>
      1 d =  Result_analysis(0.95)
      2 d.read_file(1)
----> 3 d.extract_arrays(d.read_file(1))

<ipython-input-91-06bc29de002c> in extract_arrays(self, file_number)
     15 
     16     def extract_arrays(self,file_number):
---> 17         df = Result_analysis().read_file(file_number)
     18         avgTP_10s_arr = []
     19         avgTP_100s_arr = []

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'confidence_interval'
```

I get the above given error.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please show the error you get.

Comment: How do I use it then? I'm a beginner and maybe not doing it correctly.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-3a6ba33dfac9> in <module>
      1 d =  Result_analysis(0.95)
----> 2 d.extract_arrays()

TypeError: extract_arrays() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df'

Comment: You are calling `d.extract_arrays()` without giving it an argument, but since you have defined it as `def extract_arrays(self, df)` (`d` is implicitly passed as `self`), it requires one more argument, which you did not provide. This is what the error message is telling you.

Comment: You need to use the method like `d.extract_arrays(something)` where `something` will be known as `df` inside the method. Whether this `something` comes from another method of the same class is not relevant.

Comment: 'df' is the returned value from the first method so how do I pass it to the next method? I know it should be supplied an additional argument but I somehow want to from this first method and giver it to the second one. Does it make any sense?

Comment: Please show the code where you create `d` and call the methods ([edit] the question, do not post the code as a comment).

Comment: Delete line 17, as well as the line `d.read_file(1)`. Edit: oh wait, you've changed more... basically go back to the original code you posted here, but instead of `d.extract_arrays()` use `d.extract_arrays(d.read_file(1))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include all your code, and you should have updated the question with the traceback, but did you mean this:

```
n = ...  # I don't know what n is.
d = Result_analysis(0.95)
print(d.extract_arrays(d.read_file(n))
```

Comment: Yes, I want to do a similar thing which enables me to take return value from the first method and pass it to the next method.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to call the function read_file explicitly from outside class. then you can convert the program as:

```
class Result_analysis():
    def __init__(self, confidence_interval):
        self.confidence_interval = confidence_interval

    def read_file(self, file_number):
        dict_ = {1: 'Ten_Runs_avg-throughput_scalar.csv',
                 2: 'Thirty_Runs_avg-throughput_scalar.csv',
                 3: 'Hundred_Runs_avg-throughput_scalar.csv',
                 4: 'Thousand_Runs_avg-throughput_scalar.csv'}
        cols = ['run', 'ber', 'timelimit', 'repetition', 'Module', 'Avg_Throughput']
        data = pd.read_csv(dict_[file_number], delimiter=',', skiprows=[0], names=cols)

        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        return df

    def extract_arrays(self,file_number):
        df = Result_analysis().read_file(file_number)
        avgTP_10s_arr = []
        avgTP_100s_arr = []
        avgTP_1000s_arr = []

        for i in range(len(data)):
            if (df['timelimit'][i] == 10):
                avgTP_10s_arr.append(df['Avg_Throughput'][i])
            elif (df['timelimit'][i] == 100):
                avgTP_100s_arr.append(df['Avg_Throughput'][i])
            elif (df['timelimit'][i] == 1000):
                avgTP_1000s_arr.append(df['Avg_Throughput'][i])
        return avgTP_10s_arr, avgTP_100s_arr, avgTP_1000s_arr
```

call the function `extract_arrays`, and pass `file_number` as parameter

Comment: I get the following error!
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-9991d5a19b1f> in <module>
      1 d =  Result_analysis(0.95)
----> 2 d.extract_arrays(d.read_file(1))

<ipython-input-84-06bc29de002c> in extract_arrays(self, file_number)
     15 
     16     def extract_arrays(self,file_number):
---> 17         df = Result_analysis().read_file(file_number)
     18         avgTP_10s_arr = []
     19         avgTP_100s_arr = []

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'confidence_interval'

Comment: The one time it might make sense to create a `Result_analysis` object within its own class is if `extract_arrays()` were a class function or static function. It typically makes no sense in a member function.

Comment: replace the line ```df = Result_analysis().read_file(file_number)``` 

as 

```conf_int = "something you already know"```

```df = Result_analysis(conf_int).read_file(file_number) ```